# How to append a div to where a user has clicked on the page in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cursor

I am having trouble appending a div to anywhere a user has clicked on the page

**For example**

If a user clicks on the side of the page it should append a div on the exact spot they clicked and if they clicked in the middle of the page it should append a div to the exact spot they clicked and so on and so forth

**Here's the code I have so far**

```
$('body').click(function(e){
        console.log("X: " + e.pageX + " Y: " + e.pageY);
});
```

this is for getting the x, y cords for where the user has clicked

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks,

Arnav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to listen to `click` event first add the `listener` to `document`. On click, create new element and set the `left` and `top` property with values of `x` and `y` co-ordinates.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML= `<span>New Content</span>`;
    div.style.position = "absolute";
    div.style.left = e.x + 'px';
    div.style.top = e.y + 'px';
    document.body.appendChild(div);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but is there any way I can add html to this div?  

Comment: @fuzzybuddy - Yes. Use `innerHTML` instead of `textContent`. See edit. If the answer solves the problem mark it as accepted so as to indicate that problem has been resolved.

Comment: I have tried innerHTML but it says that innerHTML is not defined

Comment: Is it `cannot set innerHTML of undefined` or `innerHTML is not defined`?

Comment: innerHTML is not defined

Comment: @fuzzybuddy - It seems like the element of which you are changing the `innerHTML` property is `undefined`. If that does not solve your problem, please add your complete code.

Comment: thanks dude your code works i've upvoted and ticked your answer have a nice day 

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style it with CSS (position) you gotta look at the event for coordinates. Then use CSS position absolute if the parent is non-static position. Another alternative is to use position: fixed which is relative to the viewport (or top of the document? can’t remember)

`document.body.addEventListener(‘click’, event => event.target.appendChild(document.createElement(‘div’)))`

Some elements (input/labels) can’t have children, so you might have to make sure the target is a valid node

This should work bc of event propagation (event.currentTarget should be the body, but whatever was clicked is likely the event.target)